# Property initialization in Constructor using params C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, parameters, constructor

I used `params` keywords in the constructor of a class as:

```
public class EvoObject  
{
   private Object _ID;
   private List<Tuple<List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>, List<Int32>, List<Int32>>> _attributes;  
   // ...other properties...  

   public EvoObject(Object _ID, params List<Int32>[] _args)
   {
      Debug.Assert(_args.Length >= 2, "Invalid attributes!");
      this._ID = _ID;
      _attributes = new List<List<Int32>>(_args.Length);

      for (int _i = 0; _i < _args.Length; _i++)
      {
         _attributes.Add(_args[_i]);
      }
}
```

whereas the parameters to be received by the constructor

```
public EvoObject(Object _ID, params List<Int32>[] _args)  
{ ... }
```

are as:

```
return new EvoObject(_author, _Papers, _CoAuthors, _Venues);
```

i.e. a method which returns to constructor.

The parameter`_author` will go to `_ID` and other three parameters will go to `_args`. The parameters `_Papers`, `_CoAuthors`, `_Venues` are defined as:

```
List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> _Papers;  
List<Int32> _CoAuthors;  
List<Int32> _Venues;
```

Now how to define `params` in the constructor so that it'll accommodate all three parameters of defined types. Currently, `params` is defined as `List<Int32>[] _args` which can accommodate `_CoAuthors` and `_Venues` but not `_Papers` because of *data type* of this parameter i.e. `List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>`.

*I also presume that the way I defined property i.e. `_attributes` in class `EvoObject` as `private List<List<Int32>> _attributes` might also get changed.*

How and which *data type* should be used for `params` in the constructor here?
**EDIT**
I tried to define my constructor as:

```
public EvoObject( Object _ID,  
                  List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>_papers,  
                  List<Int32> _coAuthors,  
                  List<Int32> _venues
                )
{
   this._ID = _ID; 
   //int _m = Math.Max(_papers.Count, _coAuthors.Count); 
   //int _maxSize = Math.Max(_m, _venues.Count);
   _attributes = new List<Tuple<List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>, List<Int32>, List<Int32>>>  
                     ();

   for (int _i = 0; _i < _attributes.Count; _i++)
   {
      _attributes.Add(new Tuple<List<Dictionary<int, int>>, List<int>, List<int>>  
                     (_papers, _coAuthors, _venues));
   }
}
```

Is it fine?

Comment: Sorry - Off Topic to your question - but what do you perceive as the benefit to prefixing *all* variables/parameters with an underscore?

Comment: I've just got used to it i.e. using variable names starting with an underscore, nothing special within it by the way.

Comment: The Type must be a Type that all of them have in common in their inheritance chain. The 'lowest' Type they have in common is the non-generic `IList`. That's probably not what you want. You're using the wrong tool to fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `params` keyword to specify more then one type of parameters, nor can you use it twice in the same method (or constructor).
However, Your text indicates there is actually no need to use the `params` keyword anyway - you can simply write your constructor like this:

```
public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors, 
                 List<Int32> venues)
{
    // constructor logic...
}
```

And if you need another option (like, without venues) you can simply overload the constroctor:

```
public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors)
{
    // constructor logic...
}
```

and in that case, your more elaborate signature constructor would be this:

```
public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors, 
                 List<Int32> venues)
    :this(id, papers, coAuthors)
{
    // constructor logic to handle venues...
}
```

### Edit:

You can't store a `List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>` inside a `List<List<Int32>>`, so you need to add a different property for `papers`.

```
private Object _ID;
private List<List<Int32>> _attributes;
private List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> _papers;

public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors, 
                 List<Int32> venues)
{
    _Id = id;
    _papers = papers;
    _attributes = new List<List<Int32>>();
    _attributes.add(coAuthors);
    _attributes.add(venues);
}
```

While I'm editing, I'll add Heinzi's suggestion as well, However I prefer the way I've written it (though it is a matter of personal preference, I guess):

```
public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors, 
                 List<Int32> venues)
{
    // all constructor logic goes in one constructor
}

public EvoObject(Object id, 
                 List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>> papers, 
                 List<Int32> coAuthors)
    :this(id, papers, coAuthors, null)
{
    // nothing else here
}
```

Comment: Either this, or `EvoObject(... id, ... papers, ... coAuthors) : this(id, papers, coAuthors, null) {}`, if you want to have your complete constructor logic in one place.

Comment: If not to use `params` but I'm still afraid about how'll I define the property i.e. `_attributes` in class `EvoObject` because I have to add all three (from end) parameters to this property afterwards that is suppose to be inside the constructor initialization.

Comment: Using your suggestion, how to initialize `_attributes` (a property of class) inside constructor ?

Comment: @Zohar--please also add property initialization inside your constructor definition.

Comment: But `_papers` is also one of our `_attributes` I wish to add `_papers` with `_attributes` too. Is it possible ? While I tried to define `_attributes` as:  
`private List<Tuple<List<Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>, List<Int32>, List<Int32>>> _attributes;` is it fine ?

Comment: You can't put apples and oranges in the same basket. a `List<Dictionaty<int, int>>` can't be stored inside a List`<List<int>>`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have edited my question with my tried constructor definition using `Tuple` please have a look and suggest best

Comment: By using this constructor definition, will we be able to have an object ID and a list of attributes ?

Comment: not really a list, but all attributes will be a part of the same property, yes.